# HTML/CSS: Add shadow to clip-path not working

Tags: html, css, shadow

I want to add shadow to my clip-path, but if I wrap it it will disappear.

Here is the result I want (must the shadow to the clip-path):

```css
.question-card {
  background-color: silver;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  height: 100px; 
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 1px 7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.inset {
  height: 40px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 208px;
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
  border-radius: 0 0.25em 0.25em 0;
}

.inset-wrap {
  filter: drop-shadow(-1px 1px 7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75));
}
```

```html
<div class="question-card">

    <span class="inset"></span>

</div>
```

Here is the result when I try to add the shadow why it disappears?:

```css
.question-card {
  background-color: silver;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  height: 100px; 
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 1px 7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.inset {
  height: 40px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 208px;
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
  border-radius: 0 0.25em 0.25em 0;
}

.inset-wrap {
  filter: drop-shadow(-1px 1px 7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75));
}
```

```html
<div class="question-card">
    <span class="inset-wrap">
        <span class="inset"></span>
    </span>

</div>
```

Comment: .inset {
  height: 40px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 208px;
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
  border-radius: 0 0.25em 0.25em 0;
}
at
background-color: inherit;
use silver color

Answer (score 2):

```css
.question-card {
  background-color: silver;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  height: 100px; 
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 1px 7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.inset {
  height: 40px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: silver;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 208px;
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
  border-radius: 0 0.25em 0.25em 0;
}

.inset-wrap {
  filter: drop-shadow(-1px 1px 7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75));
}
```

```html
<div class="question-card">
    <span class="inset-wrap">
        <span class="inset"></span>
    </span>

</div>
```